# Ettus UHD, compiling Transceiver52M

Tags: usrp, uhd

I have a problem compiling Transceiver52M for OpenBTS, I have a Ettus B200 peripheral, and have installed UHD version UHD_003.010.git-156-g2d68f228.

But I get the following errors once I get to compiling Transceiver52M; the filing lines are (the full build output is [here](http://pastebin.com/QbK1CSfZ)):

```
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -rdynamic -DTIMESTAMP_ISO=\"2016-03-28T20:57:00\" -o transceiver runTransceiver.o /usr/local/lib/libuhd.so  ./.libs/libtransceiver.a ../GSM/.libs/libGSM.a ../C
ommonLibs/.libs/libcommon.a -ldl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so -la53 -lzmq -pthread
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::stop()':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:673: undefined reference to `uhd::stream_cmd_t::stream_cmd_t(uhd::stream_cmd_t::stream_mode_t const&)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::set_rx_gain(double, unsigned long)':
/usr/local/include/uhd/usrp/multi_usrp.hpp:500: undefined reference to `uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::ALL_GAINS'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::set_tx_gain(double, unsigned long)':
/usr/local/include/uhd/usrp/multi_usrp.hpp:786: undefined reference to `uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::ALL_GAINS'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::writeSamples(short*, int, bool*, unsigned long long, bool)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:810: undefined reference to `uhd::tx_metadata_t::tx_metadata_t()'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:814: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::from_ticks(long long, double)'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:847: undefined reference to `uhd::get_version_string()'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::uhd_device(int, bool)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:343: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::time_spec_t(long, double)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::parse_dev_type()':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:479: undefined reference to `uhd::device::get_tree() const'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:480: undefined reference to `uhd::fs_path::fs_path(char const*)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `rx_metadata_t':
/usr/local/include/uhd/types/metadata.hpp:37: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::time_spec_t(double)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd::rx_metadata_t::reset()':
/usr/local/include/uhd/types/metadata.hpp:45: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::time_spec_t(double)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::restart(uhd::time_spec_t)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:629: undefined reference to `uhd::stream_cmd_t::stream_cmd_t(uhd::stream_cmd_t::stream_mode_t const&)'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:637: undefined reference to `uhd::stream_cmd_t::stream_cmd_t(uhd::stream_cmd_t::stream_mode_t const&)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::start()':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:654: undefined reference to `uhd::msg::register_handler(void (* const&)(uhd::msg::type_t, std::string const&))'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:660: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::time_spec_t(double)'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:663: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::get_real_secs() const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `smpl_buf::avail_smpls(uhd::time_spec_t) const':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:987: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::to_ticks(double) const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `smpl_buf::read(void*, unsigned long, uhd::time_spec_t)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:1033: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::to_ticks(double) const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `smpl_buf::write(void*, unsigned long, uhd::time_spec_t)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:1074: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::to_ticks(double) const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::init_gains()':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:359: undefined reference to `uhd::meta_range_t::meta_range_t()'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::get_tx_gain_range(unsigned long)':
/usr/local/include/uhd/usrp/multi_usrp.hpp:838: undefined reference to `uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::ALL_GAINS'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::init_gains()':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:362: undefined reference to `uhd::meta_range_t::start() const'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:363: undefined reference to `uhd::meta_range_t::stop() const'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:366: undefined reference to `uhd::meta_range_t::start() const'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:367: undefined reference to `uhd::meta_range_t::stop() const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::setTxFreq(double)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:862: undefined reference to `uhd::tune_request_t::tune_request_t(double)'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:863: undefined reference to `uhd::tune_result_t::to_pp_string() const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::setRxFreq(double)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:871: undefined reference to `uhd::tune_request_t::tune_request_t(double)'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:872: undefined reference to `uhd::tune_result_t::to_pp_string() const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::open(std::string const&, bool)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:531: undefined reference to `uhd::device_addr_t::device_addr_t(std::string const&)'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:532: undefined reference to `uhd::device::find(uhd::device_addr_t const&, uhd::device::device_filter_t)'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:539: undefined reference to `uhd::device_addr_t::to_string() const'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:541: undefined reference to `uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(uhd::device_addr_t const&)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `stream_args_t':
/usr/local/include/uhd/stream.hpp:63: undefined reference to `uhd::device_addr_t::device_addr_t(std::string const&)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::open(std::string const&, bool)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:543: undefined reference to `uhd::device_addr_t::to_string() const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::str_code(uhd::rx_metadata_t)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:925: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::get_real_secs() const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::check_rx_md_err(uhd::rx_metadata_t&, long)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:689: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::time_spec_t(double)'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:716: undefined reference to `uhd::operator<(uhd::time_spec_t const&, uhd::time_spec_t const&)'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:719: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::get_real_secs() const'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:718: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::get_real_secs() const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::readSamples(short*, int, bool*, unsigned long long, bool*, unsigned int*)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:732: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::time_spec_t(double)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `rx_metadata_t':
/usr/local/include/uhd/types/metadata.hpp:37: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::time_spec_t(double)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd::rx_metadata_t::reset()':
/usr/local/include/uhd/types/metadata.hpp:45: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::time_spec_t(double)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::readSamples(short*, int, bool*, unsigned long long, bool*, unsigned int*)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:745: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::from_ticks(long long, double)'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:746: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::get_real_secs() const'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:781: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::get_real_secs() const'
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:770: undefined reference to `uhd::get_version_string()'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::str_code(uhd::async_metadata_t)':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:958: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::get_real_secs() const'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `async_metadata_t':
/usr/local/include/uhd/types/metadata.hpp:169: undefined reference to `uhd::time_spec_t::time_spec_t(double)'
./.libs/libtransceiver.a(UHDDevice.o): In function `uhd_device::setPriority()':
/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M/UHDDevice.cpp:683: undefined reference to `uhd::set_thread_priority_safe(float, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [transceiver] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/openbts/dev/openbts/Transceiver52M'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/openbts/dev/openbts'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very symptomatic of having multiple competing UHD installations. Maybe you've installed UHD from your Linux Distro's repository and then installed UHD again, manually, atop? Or maybe you've installed it when building OpenBTS.

However, make sure that you've only got one installation that your build system will find, or else you'd see exactly what you're experiencing now.

Comment: Yes it seems to be it. When I restartet my shell, I had the right settings somehow